# How to create a minimal daemon process in a swift 2 command line tool?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa, swift2

## What I am trying to do

I want to run a daemon process that can listen to OSX system events like `NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification` in an `command line tool` xcode project? Is that possible? And if not, why not and are there any work arounds or hacks?

## Some code samples

The following sample code from a `swift 2` `cocoa application` project sets up a system event listener, which calls `WillLaunchApp` every time an OSX app gets started. (*this works just fine*)

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
            .notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                selector: "WillLaunchApp:",
                name: NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func WillLaunchApp(notification: NSNotification!) {
        print(notification)
    }
}
```

In contrast this simingly similar `swift 2` `command line tool` project **will not call** `WillLaunchApp`.

```
import Cocoa

class MyObserver: NSObject
{
    override init() {
        super.init()
        NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
            .notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                selector: "WillLaunchApp:",
                name: NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func WillLaunchApp(notification: NSNotification!) {
        // is never called
        print(notification)
    }
}

let observer = MyObserver()

while true {
    // simply to keep the command line tool alive - as a daemon process
    sleep(1)
}
```

I am guessing I am missing some `cocoa` and/or `xcode` fundamentals here, but I cannot figure out which ones. Maybe it is related to the while-true loop, which might be blocking the events. If so, is there a **correct** way to run a **daemon** process?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out using `while true` loop does block the main-thread.
Simply replace the `while true` loop with `NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().run()` and you have a daemon process.

I read the sources of [swifter](https://github.com/glock45/swifter) (a swift-based server), which is doing the same.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 3 and later, the equivalent code is:

```
RunLoop.main.run()
```