# Swift 3 NSNotificationCenter Keyboardwillshow/hide

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, swift3

I have a piece of code that worked in Swift 2 and I tried using Xcode to update the code to the newest version and I fixed everything except two issues.

I have this code :

```
let loginvc: LoginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

That pairs along with this:

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    constraint.constant = -100
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    constraint.constant = 25
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

On the first part I now get an error saying

> Type 'LoginViewController' has no member 'keyboardWillShow/Hide'

I don't understand why it is not seeing the method underneath.

Does anybody know a solution to this issue?

Comment: did u add the NotificationCenter inside viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() method?

Comment: Change `LoginViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)` to `LoginViewController.keyboardWillShow(notification:)`?

Comment: Tried that, and xCode wants me to add the _ back in

Comment: Are you adding the NotificationCenter observers in the `LoginViewController ` class? Are both functions in this class too? Have you tried `#selector(keyboardWillShow())`?

Comment: @Dilts the funcs are in the same class and I just tried that. The Notification observers are in the viewDidLoad

Comment: Try `func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {` and `#selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:))`. Notice the added underscore in the keyboardWillHide function.

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 check out the [updated Swift Programming book](https://swift.org/documentation/#the-swift-programming-language). Page 1027 and 1028 are probably what you're looking for, you also might have to add a `@objc(keyboardWillHideWithNotification:)` to your class.

Comment: @Dilts by combining those two comments xCode allowed me to click to edit  and now its not complaining anymore...thank you

Comment: @Dilts if you want to put it as an answer i can mark it correct

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Just posted my answer! I'm glad to have helped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the updated [Swift Programming Language book](https://swift.org/documentation/#the-swift-programming-language). Pages 1027 and 1028 are what you're looking for. It should be something like this:

```
func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: NSNotification) {…
```

Notice the additional underscore above. Also:

```
#selector(LoginViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:))
```

You also might need to add `@objc(keyboardWillHideWithNotification:)` to your class.

Answer (score 5):

On Swift 4.2, addObserver name for NSNotificationCenter changed as well:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use that code that's work on swift3

You can use your ViewController (e.g, `loginvc`) to add notification

```
let loginvc : LoginVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! LoginVC

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(loginvc.keyboardWillShow(notification:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
        selector: #selector(loginvc.keyboardWillHide(notification:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Then add keyboard hide and show method

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print("Show") 
    }
}
func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print("Hide")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NSNotificationCenter have things alter for get show keyboard:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NovaVisitaVC.abreTeclado(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(NovaVisitaVC.abreTeclado(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```