# How to move StatView programmatically when keyboard shows

Tags: swift, uistackview, uikeyboard

I have a login page which has two textviews and a button in a stackView 
I'm trying to move the stackview when the keyboard shows and also disappears as I want to know how to do this programmatically

Answer (score -1):

iOS sends 2 notifications when keyboard will show/hide

```
UIKeyboardWillShow

UIKeyboardWillHide
```

What you can do, is observe those notifications, and move the frame of your stackView such as

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow() {
    if stackView.frame.origin.y == 0 {
      stackView.frame.origin.y -= 200
   }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide() {
     if stackView.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        stackView.frame.origin.y = 0
      }
 }
```

And here is how to observe those notification. (use this code in your viewDidLoad function)

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

Comment: I added that code but get this error,                                                                        Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member 'UIResponder'

Comment: Notification name is UIViewController.keyboardWillShow and UIViewController.keyboardWillHide.

Can you try ?

Comment: That works, but now its saying  Use of unresolved identifier 'stackView'  it won't let me access the stackView when I'm using the if statement

Comment: Remplace "stackView" with the name of your actual stack view...

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()   
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide), name: UIWindow.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

   @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
         print("keyboardWillShow")
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
         print("keyboardWillHide")
    }
```

If still got any error check below link:

[LINK FOR KEYBOARD HIDE/SHOW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875973/how-to-write-keyboard-notifications-in-swift-3)