# NSNotificationCenter Swift 3.0 on keyboard show and hide

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard-events, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to run a function when the keyboard shows and disappears and have the following code:

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyBoardUp(Notification :)), name:  NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

And the function `keyBoardUp` below:

```
func keyBoardUp( Notification: NSNotification){
    print("HELLO")
}
```

However the function doesn't print to the console when the keyboard shows. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Change selector to `#selector(ViewController.keyBoardUp(notification:))` and function to `func keyBoardUp( notification: Notification){
    print("HELLO")
}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 NSNotificationCenter Keyboardwillshow/hide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825327/swift-3-nsnotificationcenter-keyboardwillshow-hide)

Comment: In swift 3, shouldn't you be getting a compiler error at the function?

Answer (score 43):

#### Swift 3:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        print("notification: Keyboard will show")
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

#### Swift 4.2.1:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        // Do something with size
    }
}

@objc fileprivate func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        // Do something with size
    }
}
```

**Swift 4.2+**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code wil get fail , keyboard active ,type anyting , dont resign and press lock button of iphone and then little bit later unlock your iphone  , your view will be not visiible

Comment: I got around that by hardcoding the keyboardSize.height (since I didn't want to move the entire view by the height of the keyboard, as it was only covering the intended area partially. So instead of that part you can enter an Int

Comment: Use UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey to get correct height, and on iPad there are different keyboards heights (w or w/o hardware keyboard) - hardcoding the height will lead to trouble.

Answer (score 28):

### Swift 4.2+

[@vandana's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719907/7734643) answer updated to reflect *changes* to native Notifications in Swift 4.2.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you need to use `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` to account for `safeAreaInset` changes introduced with **iOS 11**.

Comment: It is UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification notification name

Comment: I needed the @objc keyword on the functions too.

Comment: @RobEllis yes those are required from Swift 4+. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Do remember to add your observers in viewWillAppear and remove them on viewWillDisappear

Comment: @AmeyaVichare https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822456/7734643

Answer (score 6):

set keyboard notification observer in

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
}
```

and in your function handle it

```
func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
  print("keyboard displayed!!")
}
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 4.X / 5

I like the inline, block-based approach which is available for a long time already! You can read more about the parameters of `addObserver(...)` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver).

Some advantages of this approach are:

- you don't need to use the @objc keyword
- you write your callback code at the same location where you setup your observer

> **Important:** Call `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer)` in the `deinit` of the object where you set register the observer (often a view controller).

```swift
let center = NotificationCenter.default

let keyboardWillShowObserver: NSObjectProtocol = center.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
    guard let value = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    let height = value.cgRectValue.height

    // use the height of the keyboard to layout your UI so the prt currently in
    // foxus remains visible
}

let keyboardWillHideObserver: NSObjectProtocol = center.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in

    // restore the layout of your UI before the keyboard has been shown
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for swift:

```
// MARK:- Kyeboard hide/show methods

func keyboardWasShown(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}

func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWasShown(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == mEnterPasswordTextField || textField == mEnterConfirmPassword  {
            animateViewMoving(up: true, moveValue: 120)
    }
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == mEnterPasswordTextField || textField == mEnterConfirmPassword  {
            animateViewMoving(up: false, moveValue: 120)
    }
}

func animateViewMoving (up:Bool, moveValue :CGFloat){
    let movementDuration:TimeInterval = 0.3
    let movement:CGFloat = ( up ? -moveValue : moveValue)
    UIView.beginAnimations( "animateView", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(movementDuration )
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0,  dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
```

***// In viewDidLoad()***

```
self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
self.deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications()
```

Answer (score 2):

### KeyBoard Will Show And Hide With TxtField In Swift 4

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var commentsTxt: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var keyboardBottom: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = false
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil
    )
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(keyboarddidHide),
        name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil
    )
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardFrame: NSValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.cgRectValue
        let keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        self.keyboardBottom.constant = keyboardHeight - self.bottomLayoutGuide.length
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.1, execute: {
            let bottomOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.scrlView.contentSize.height - self.scrlView.bounds.size.height)
            self.scrlView.setContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true)
        })
    }
}
@objc func keyboarddidHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    self.keyboardBottom.constant = 0
    
}

   override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
     NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidHide, object: nil)
}

 @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      if(messageCount > 0)
      {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item:messageCount - 1, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
      }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if(messageCount > 0)
    {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(item:0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceiveKeyboardNotificationObserver(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didReceiveKeyboardNotificationObserver(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

@objc func didReceiveKeyboardNotificationObserver(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo
    let keyboardBounds = (userInfo!["UIKeyboardBoundsUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardFrame = (userInfo!["UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let duration = userInfo!["UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey"] as! Double
    let curve = userInfo!["UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey"] as! Int
    let frameBegin = (userInfo!["UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let centerBegin = (userInfo!["UIKeyboardCenterBeginUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgPointValue
    let center = (userInfo!["UIKeyboardCenterEndUserInfoKey"] as! NSValue).cgPointValue
    let location = userInfo!["UIKeyboardIsLocalUserInfoKey"] as! Int
    println("keyboardBounds: \(keyboardBounds) \nkeyboardFrame: \(keyboardFrame) \nduration: \(duration) \ncurve: \(curve) \nframeBegin:\(frameBegin) \ncenterBegin:\(centerBegin)\ncenter:\(center)\nlocation:\(location)")
    switch notification.name {
    case UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification:
    // keyboardWillShowNotification
    case UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification:
    // keyboardWillHideNotification
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### **Swift 4.2**

This version works both on the iPhone 5 and the iPhone X. It works very well if you respect the safe area during your constraints settings.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let _ = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
            if self.emailTextField.isFirstResponder {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= 100
            } else if self.passwordTextField.isFirstResponder {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
            } else if self.passwordConfirmTextField.isFirstResponder {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= 200
            }
        }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
           self.view.frame.origin.y = self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift > 4.++**

You can use protocol & protocol extension .
Let's create KeyboardListener Protocol

```
protocol KeyboardListener: class {
   func registerKeyboardObserver()
   func keyboardDidUpdate(keyboardHeight: CGFloat)
   func removeObserver()
}
```

Then create @objc function into UIViewController extension

```
extension UIViewController {
@objc func adjustForKeyboard(notification: Notification) {
    guard let keyboardValue = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue else { return }
    
    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = keyboardValue.cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)
    
    if notification.name == UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification {
        if let keyboardLister = self as? KeyboardListener {
            keyboardLister.keyboardDidUpdate(keyboardHeight: .zero)
        }
    } else {
        if let keyboardLister = self as? KeyboardListener {
            keyboardLister.keyboardDidUpdate(keyboardHeight: keyboardViewEndFrame.height - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then, use Keyboard listener extension for default implementations

```
extension KeyboardListener where Self: UIViewController {
func registerKeyboardObserver() {
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(adjustForKeyboard), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification, object: nil)
}

func removeObserver() {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

}

Finally , we can use it from our ViewController class

```
extension EditProfileVC: KeyboardListener {
func keyboardDidUpdate(keyboardHeight: CGFloat) {
    //update view when keyboard appear, 
}
```

}

And call register from viewwillAppear & removeObserver from deinit

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    registerKeyboardObserver()
}

deinit {
   removeObserver()
}
```