# How to fix position of UIView when keyboard moved up?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, keyboard, uitextfield

How do I fix the position of `UIView` with `image` and `label` when the keyboard is moved up?

I made a code to move up my `textField` when the keyboard shows, but instead this moves everything.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    moveTextField(textField: rasstoyanietextField, moveDistance: -215, up: false)
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    moveTextField(textField: rasstoyanietextField, moveDistance: -215, up: true)
}


func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    rasstoyanietextField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}


func moveTextField(textField: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool){
    let moveDuration = 0.1
    let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)

    UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
    self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
    UIView.commitAnimations()

}
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: You better use notification. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718520/nsnotificationcenter-swift-3-0-on-keyboard-show-and-hide)

Comment: 1. Do not hardcode a keyboard height. 2. You never use the `textField` parameter of your `moveTextField` method. 3. Use the block version of UIView animations. It's much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you move whole view, instead of textview only. Change line:

```
self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
```

with:

```
textField.frame = textField.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add keybaord observers

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShow),
                name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidShow,
                object: nil)


            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(handleKeyboardWillHide),
                name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,
                object: nil)
```

I think it's better to use scrollviews in viewControllers that have textfeilds/textViews to move up all items when showing but here you may Hook the bottom constraint of the textfeild or it's superview and drag it as IBOutlet and do this

```
 @objc func handleKeyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

          self.textFeilfBottomCon.constant = -1 * keyboardSize.height

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

         })


    }
}

@objc func handleKeyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {

            self.textFeilfBottomCon.constant = 0

             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

              self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

         })

    }
}
```