# How to implement "move view with keyboard" function into textfield

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nsnotifications

I want to implement that function into my textfield's function. I tried it different ways but I couldn't succeed.
Here is the code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSNotificationCenter Swift 3.0 on keyboard show and hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41718520/nsnotificationcenter-swift-3-0-on-keyboard-show-and-hide)

Answer (score 1):

You're using key `UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` which cause that you get wrong height.

Use this key instead:

```
UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey
```