# How to stick my button to the bottom of the view using SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am experimenting with SwiftUI and just trying to have a button at the bottom. Right now it is centered. Wondering how I could force a view to stick superview's bottom as you would do in AutoLayout.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Add a Spacer() above the Text.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You have to add a `Spacer` view above the text.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer() // ←- here
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scrollview to make your long content to not take header and footer place. Like this code:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Group { // Let say this is your sticky header 
            }
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) { 
                // This is your long content wrap in here 
            }
            Group { // And this is your sticky footer 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not working for me on iOS 14 if ScrollView has TextField and keyboard appears. Bottom Group content move above to keyboard. Please let me know the solution.

Comment: You can trigger .isHidden on the bottom Group when the keyboard appears using delegation or notificationcenter (how to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52426407/5834822). and isHidden value set to State variable.