# SWIFT 3, Eureka: When using a navigation controller, the keyboardWillShow callback is not called

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, eureka-forms

## Scenario

- NavigationController is a root controller of a TabBarController
- TabBarController has 2 UIViewControllers
- One UIViewController has a function that presents another UIViewController
- UIVIewController that is presented has a StackView
- Instantiates a subclass of FormController (eg: FormVC) and adds to Stack as subview

### Problem

The `keyboardWillShow` function of FormVC does not get called. The keyboard actually adds the input to the row, but the auto scrolling does not happen

Is this only a problem in Eureka or perhaps a problem using the Navigation controller's `pushViewController`?

Comment: Need to test if it is possible to add the Notification Observer when pushing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37825327/swift-3-nsnotificationcenter-keyboardwillshow-hide

Comment: Posted to Eureka issue list: https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/1045

Comment: Because the FormVC is just instantiated within another VC, it seems something gets lost. Managed to have it working properly when being set in the Storyboard within a ContainerView's, as the ViewController class type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

The correct way to use the FormVC is with the Container, as per the comment in the question.

Here is a great explanation credit to [Miguel Revetria](https://github.com/m-revetria) - [source](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/1045), github:

> Hi chefren the problem with your approach is that the
>   `FormViewController` lifecycle is not being handled because you are not
>   adding it to the view controllers hierarchy. Actually you are only
>   adding its view to one of your views.
>
> The function `keyboardWillShow` is not being called due to the
>   `FormViewController` adds this observer to the notification
>   `Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow` from the function `viewWillAppear`,
>   which in your case is not being called. As this, other stuff may not
>   work properly, because the view controller lifecycle is not being
>   handled.
>
> That is not the way the `FormViewController` should be used. Using it in
>   that way may end up with an undesired behavior like you experienced.
>   The correct way to embed a `FormViewController` in other view
>   controller's view is by adding it as a Child View Controller. See this
>   Apple guide for further information [Implementing a Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) View
>   Controller. Additionally, in storyboards you can use a `Container
>   View`.
>
> Regards

Comment: Still getting this message on the console might mean I need to add the keyboardWillHide notification pass: `Reading from private effective user settings.`